# SwiftMailer Batch email times my Server out

Tags: php, email, batch-file, timeout, swiftmailer

I realise that batchEmail is no longer part of the new SwiftMailer. So I made this script:

```
<?
//
// GC PRESS EMAILER v5
//
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once("config.php");
include_once("hawkmail/mail/lib/swift_required.php");
$c=mysql_connect($dbh,$dbu,$dbp);
function SendEmail(){
    // DB
    $s=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `newgc`.`press_list`");
    // Process Color Listing Loop
    while($r=mysql_fetch_array($s)){
    // ###########################
    // START LOOP
    // ###########################
        $name=$r['name'];
        $email=$r['email'];
        $to=array(''.$email.''=>''.$name.'');
        include("hawkmail/templates/press.php");
        # Email subject
        $str=$name;
        $str=substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, ' '));
        $subject='Dear '.$str.', you are invited to our Exclusive Party Collection Press Day!';
        # send message
        include("hawkmail/settings.php");       
    }
    // ###########################
    // END LOOP
    // ###########################
}
SendEmail();
?>
```

The database has 200 records. And I ran the script and it sends a few emails and then times out

> 504 Gateway Time-out

The `name` and `email` records are like

John Smith 
John.smith@site.com

Very plain. And my `hawkmail/settings.php` is this:

```
# mail
$smpturl="smtp.sendgrid.net";
$mailu="sitesitesite";
$mailp="sitessssssssssss";
$from=array("no-reply@site.com"=>"site.com");

# login credentials & setup Swift mailer parameters
$transport=Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance($smpturl, 587);
$transport->setUsername($mailu);
$transport->setPassword($mailp);
$swift=Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

# create a message (subject)
$message=new Swift_Message($subject);

# attach the body of the email
$message->setFrom($from);
$message->setBody($html, 'text/html');

$message->setTo($to);
$message->addPart($text, 'text/plain');

# actually send the message
if($recipients=$swift->send($message, $failures)){}else{}
```

Is there anyway to increase the limit of PHP time out (I use Ubuntu and Nginx) or is there an alternative to BatchMail() really don't understand why it was removed.

**Can someone post examples of Batch mail scripts using the new swiftmailer?**

Comment: Your loop should have worked I think. How about increasing server memory if cloud box to quickly execute the script? If running via browser maybe do a background task? (I dont know how to do on nginx or ubuntu if not got cPanel)

Comment: PHP has a timeout limit you need a cron job I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sending emails is the most complicated thing to do online.

It is the second most used service and the most abused.

I built my own custom email platform for sending bulk emails.

The timeout you experience is because of the Apache and PHP execution limits.

You need to run it as a CLI application with `set_time_limit (0);`

`php /path/to/app/script.php` something like this straight in the console.

If you do not have SSH access then run it with `shell_exec` like this:

```
shell_exec("php /path/to/app/script.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
```

This will ensure that the script that calls it does not hang around till it finishes.

Comment: `I built my own custom email platform for sending bulk emails.` Out of interest can you explain a little - is it opensource?

Comment: Nop. Not yet finished. So far I have the SMTP part done, still need to do the POP3 and IMAP, but that is one of my least concerns. I mainly needed the delivery and receiving part done in order to be able to send bulk emails and receive bounces that I can nicely parse on the spot and add to the delivery reports in order to identify if there are any invalid email addresses or other reason for failed delivery. I like doing things from scratch and something like this will shine on my resume. I will make parts of it public at some stage.

Comment: do use Sendgrid as an SMTP service ? If not I recommend me. Even their integration and dev guides are simple to follow and adapt - best if your a Rackspace customer it is free.

Comment: Nop. Like I said I built everything myself. From scratch with just Python, PHP and Notepad.